# best way to check for sub-string

Tags: python-3.x

I have a list of standard job names which all databases should have, like "dbname.archivebackup.b", "dbname.logbackup.b", "dbname.fullbackup.b", "dbname.dailybackup.b".

Now I need to check if these 4 jobs are present for all servers.
So i am retreiving the existing list of jobs in the form of a list like `['ora123.archivebackup.b', 'ora123.logbackup.b', 'ora123.fullbackup.b', 'ora123.dailybackup.b']`.

I am trying to compare if the sub-string 'archivebackup.b' is present in any of the elements of the list to check if the job is present; and the same for other jobs as well. Is below the right way? Or a switch case is better? I wanted to check if the job is present and also return a message if any of the job is missing.

```
for job in list:
   if ("archivebackup.b" in job) or ("logbackup.b" in job) or ("fullbackup.b" in job) or ("dailybackup.b" in job):
```

Now we have a function that takes 'files' and 'jobs' as input and checks for the matches in each job.
files = {'archivebackup.b', 'logbackup.b', 'fullbackup.b', 'dailybackup.b'}
jobs=['oracledb1.archivebackup.b','oracledb1.logbackup.b','oracledb1.fullbackup.b','oracledb1.dailybackup.b']
How can we add another check to the function where it iterates through a set of db's below and checks for the string combination of 'dbanme' and 'files' for each DB.
dbname=['ora123','ora456']

Comment: Python doesn't *have* a switch case. Is what you've shown *working*? What does right/better/best mean to you?

Comment: i meant if we can implement something like a switch case.
The if condition will check each element with the 4 substrings,but i am not sure how to proceed next i.e if it is present should i put a counter like count+1 and see if the count=4 which would mean all 4 jobs are present.And if any job is missing how to proceed,like how to print that a job is missing

Comment: I have submitted an answer to what I believed you meant by your question. That said, your question is a bit unclear (I've also submitted an edit to make your post more readable, but it still needs work, IMO). Also, you'd better edit the question title, because it's super unclear. If I've gotten your intention correctly, a better title would be "Pythonic way for checking any of a list of sub-strings" or something to that effect.

Comment: @Elektito Thanks... :) i too gave a thought on what the title should be,but couldn't decide precisely.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The other answer is inefficient since it searches through `job` for every substring you are looking for. Instead use `regex` to find anything you want:

```
import re
jobs = ['The file archivebackup.b is not here']
files = {'archivebackup.b', 'logbackup.b', 'fullbackup.b', 'dailybackup.b'}
FIND_FILE = re.compile('|'.join(s for s in files))
matches = set()
for job in jobs: # From you code
    match = FIND_FILE.search(job)
    if match:
       print(match.group(0), "found") # archivebackup.b found
       matches.add(match.group(0))
print("Missing:", files - matches)
```

Note if you are matching more than one file per jobs then you should use `findall` instead of `search`:

```
...
    match = FIND_FILE.findall(job)
    if match:
       print(match, "found") # archivebackup.b found
       for ele in match:
          matches.add(ele)
...
```

Comment: can we add something in else statement to display if any job is missing

Comment: What do you mean? You need more clarification. Should EACH job contain each backup file? Or should all backup files be found after iterating through all jobs? If you add an `else` after the `if` it will catch jobs that contain no backup files.

Comment: like if 'jobs' contain only 3 matches from the substrings,how can we display which substring was not matched?

Comment: Keep track of the matches (i.e. `match.group(0)`) then after you are done iterating find the difference between the `substrings` list and the `matches` list. See the new code.

Comment: When a string is missing the print displays-Missing: {'dailybackup.b'}
But when there is nothing missing it displays - Missing: set()
How can we get it to display nothing in this case?

Comment: Change the code to use an `if` statememt. An empty set is Falsey, so assign the set subtraction to a variable and do a `if setDifference: print("Missing ...`

Comment: currently we have a set of substrings 'files' that are being checked for a match.
how to add a check for another set of substrings..say 'dbname' in the same function? The situation is that the 'files' substring is a constant set,and 'dbname' is a variable set,both of these being passes into the function.

Comment: You will have to add an example input/output ton your question. Your problem statement is confusing.

Comment: input to the function is --files = {'archivebackup.b', 'logbackup.b', 'fullbackup.b', 'dailybackup.b'}   and dbname=['oracledb1','oracledb2','oracledb3'] and jobs=['oracledb1.archivebackup.b','oracledb1.logbackup.b','oracledb1.fullbackup.b','oracledb1.dailybackup.b']
So we need to check if for each dbname the 'job' contains the 'substring'

Comment: Still not enough information. Also, comments is not the place for information ADD IT to your question.

Comment: added to the initial question

Answer (score 1):

The Pythonic way of doing that is something like this:

```
substrings = ['archivebackup.b', 'logbackup.b', 'fullbackup.b', 'dailybackup.b']
for job in list:
    if any(sub in job for sub in substrings):
        # at least one of the sub-strings matches the name
        pass
```

Comment: substrings = ['archivebackup.b', 'logbackup.b', 'fullbackup.b', 'dailybackup.b']  
    joblist=['ora123.archivebackup.b','ora123.logbackup.b','ora123.fullbackup.b','ora123.dailybackup.b']  
    count=0  
    for job in joblist:  
        if any(sub in job for sub in substrings):  
            count=count+1  
    if count==4:  
        print('all ok....job match count is',count)  
    else:  
        print('something missing')  

How can we print the exact job missing

Comment: Posting code in comments doesn't really work that well, but this sounds like a new question. Perhaps consider posting a new question? And I suggest you put some effort into making your questions better readable/understandable. That way, it's more likely to get answers.